# stop each() loop, depending on a variable,then continue it from that element (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I am trying to stop an each() loop if the user clicks in certain div, then if he clicks another div continue with the loop (from the element it was).

The thing is I am creating a variable (true/false) if he clicks the stop div, and try to pass it to the each function. However the each function only takes the variable value in its initial state and uses this false/true value for each of the loops.

I would also like to continue the loop were it was when pressing the continue button.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EDGrk/).

```
var stopp = false;

$('.a').each(function (i) {

    $(this).delay(i * 1000).animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function () {
            $(this).appendTo('#container2').css({
                opacity: 1
            })
        }
    });

    if (stopp == true) { //This value is always false
        return false;
    }

});

$('#button_stop').on('click', function () {

    stopp = true;

});

$('#button_continue').on('click', function () {

    stopp = false;

});
```

Comment: your code doesn't really make any sense. The each is done WELL before the click events are even bound.

Comment: I want to stop the loop when I click #button_stop

Comment: The loop is already stopped before you click it.

Comment: So if the loop is already stopped, then I should stop the animation, append?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point checking for `stopp` inside each loop as it gets executed instantly and animation gets queued up, which is what you see as a continuation of animations happening for each `.a`. You can instead try stop the animation on click of button and restart the animation again.

Try this:

```
 function animate() {
   $('.a', '#container1').each(function (i) { // get the boxes in container1 alone.

        $(this).delay(i * 1000).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            complete: function () {
                $(this).appendTo('#container2').css({
                    opacity: 1
                })
            }
        });
    });
}

$('#button_stop').on('click', function () {

    $('.a').stop(true, true, true); // Stop the animation

});

$('#button_continue').on('click', function () {
   animate(); // Animate again.
});

animate(); //initail startup
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AweJH/)

Comment: Thanks I didn't realise the loop is instant and animations are queued up.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.delay()`, you can just use `setInterval`:

```
var timer;

function timerFunction() {
    var $elem = $('#container1 .a').first();

    if (!$elem.length) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        return;
    }

    $elem.fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).appendTo('#container2').show();
    });
}

$('#button_stop').on('click', function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
});

$('#button_continue').on('click', function () {
    timer = setInterval(timerFunction, 1000);
}).trigger('click');
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EDGrk/11/**